# How to adjust this data structure for smaller segments in R?

Tags: r, data-structures

I have four complete signals in the following datastructure. I would like to split each signal to 360 blocks or close to it. 
Current data structure `[1:541650, 1:4]` where four signals of the length 541650, which I want to convert to the data structure `[1:360, 1:4*1505]` or similar where I created excess spaces for the data structure because `1:4*1504` would lose some tail points

```
>>> 541650*4.0
2166600.0
>>> 360*1505*4
2167200.0
```

Current data structure, current code and its contents in R

```
m1 <- matrix(1:541650, ncol=4, nrow=541650); str(m1)
#int [1:541650, 1:4] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#case: num [1:541650, 1:4] -0.675 -0.67 -0.67 -0.65 -0.65 -0.6 -0.555 -0.535 -0.52 -0.515 ...
```

Test function to the current data structure: `M.ecg.cor <- cor(M.ecg)`
Current output: 4x4 matrix

### Testing akrun's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40430229/54964) with the case example

Code

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/40429343/54964
library("corrgram")

set.seed(24)
A=541650
m1 <- matrix(1:A, ncol=4, nrow=A)

a=360; b=1505; c=4;
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/40430229/54964
m2 <- array(`length<-`(m1, a*b*c), dim = c(a,b,c))

res <- lapply(seq(dim(m2)[3]), function(i) cor(m2[,,i]))
str(res)

res2 <- lapply(res, function(x) eigen(replace(x, is.na(x), 0))$vectors[,1:2])
str(res2)

res2 <- do.call(rbind, res2) # a single matrix
dim(res2) # 6020 2

# Not Passed because output strange
corrgram(res2,
  upper.panel=panel.pie,
  lower.panel=panel.shade,
  text.panel=panel.txt,
  order=NULL,
  diag.panel=panel.minmax)
```

Output, Fig. 1 Output is only 1x1 matrix

```
List of 4
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:1505] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:1505] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:1505] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:1505] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
List of 4
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:2] -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 ...
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:2] -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 ...
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:2] -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 ...
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:2] -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 ...
[1] 6020    2
```

[image]

Expected output: 6020x6020 matrix

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: You may need to create an `array` by specifying the `dim`

Comment: `m1 <- matrix(1:20, ncol=5, nrow=4); array(m1, dim = c(2,2,5))`

Comment: I noticed that the values are not same 2166600.and 2167200.  `array` can hold only fixed dimensions.  I am not sure how you want to proceed with extra elements.  So perhaps, append NA at the end and convert to `array`

Comment: I posted a solution below.

Comment: The `cor(M.ecg)` you are currently applying on the  `541650*4.0`.  I guess you wanted to apply on each of the 4 elements of `360*1505` matrix?

Comment: The output values are all 1s in your example because the dataset created is from `1:A`.  Also, in your earlier code `cor(M.ecg)`, the `cor` is applied on a matrix?

Comment: Suppose if I use `m1 <- matrix(rnorm(A), ncol=4, nrow=A)`, then I get `str(res2)#
List of 4
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:1505] 1 -0.0186 0.0666 0.0271 -0.0199 ...
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:1505] 1 0.0469 0.0509 0.0807 -0.0428 ...
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:1505] 1 0.0509 -0.0422 0.054 -0.1068 ...
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:1505] 1 -0.00897 -0.0894 -0.08123 -0.12254 ...`  The dimensions in `cor` are based on the number of columns i.e. 1505 columns in each case.

Comment: That would be a different question as it was not clear from your original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to convert to an `array`, but `array` can hold only fixed dimensions.  So, if we fell short of number of elements, append some NAs at the end and then convert to a 3D array.

```
m2 <- array(`length<-`(m1, 30), dim = c(2,5,3))
```

and then `apply` the function by specifying the `MARGIN` as 3.

```
res <- apply(m2, 3, FUN = function(x) list(cor(x)))
identical(res[[1]][[1]], cor(m2[,,1]))
#[1] TRUE
```

Or another option is to loop through the third dimension using `lapply` and apply the `cor`

```
res2 <- lapply(seq(dim(m2)[3]), function(i) cor(m2[,,i]))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
m1 <- matrix(rnorm(45), ncol=5, nrow=9)
```

Comment: @Masi It has 3 dimensions,In your example, `360*1505*4`, the `dim = c(360, 1505, 4)` So, if you want to subset the array, say the 1st element of the 3rd dimension, `m2[,,1]`

Comment: @Masi I was just creating a small reproducible example.  Just replaced it with a new example and using `cor`

Comment: @Masi If you look at the documenation in `?cor`, there is `use` argument which can take values `"everything", "all.obs", "complete.obs", "na.or.complete", or "pairwise.complete.obs"`. and also `cor` when you apply to a matrix, it returns a matrix of correlations

Comment: @Masi If it is one big matrix, then why your approach is not getting the correct output

Comment: @Masi Sorry, I am not sure what you wanted

Comment: @Masi Your input dataset is a single matrix with a certain dimension.  The changed dataset ('m2') is a 3D array with another set of dimensions for each element along the 3rd dimension.  If you want `res2` to be a single matrix, you can have it by `do.call(rbind, res2)` or `do.call(cbind, res2)`

Comment: @Masi You are checking the `str` of the dimension, and not the `res2` i.e `dim(do.call(rbind, res2))` will give you the dimension, and `str(do.call(rbind, res2))` give the structure