# How to adjust this data structure for eigen in R?

Tags: r, data-structures, eigenvector

I have a list of corr matrices `[1:1505, 1:1505]`. 
I am thinking how to adjust them for the `Eigen` in R. 
The initial thread [How to adjust this data structure for smaller segments in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40429343/54964) consisted only one test function `cor` which was not sufficient in the end, so here the second test function - `Eigen` of the cor matrix

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/40429343/54964
set.seed(24)
A=541650
m1 <- matrix(1:A, ncol=4, nrow=A)

a=360; b=1505; c=4;
m2 <- array(`length<-`(m1, a*b*c), dim = c(a,b,c))

res <- lapply(seq(dim(m2)[3]), function(i) cor(m2[,,i]))

res2 <- lapply(res, function(x) eigen(replace(x, is.na(x), 0))$vectors[,1:2])

str(res2)

e1 <- res[,1]
e2 <- res[,2]
```

Output

```
List of 4
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:2] -0.0144 0.0512 0.0157 -0.0232 0.0248 ...
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:2] 0.02233 0.00977 -0.02361 0.01597 0.00115 ...
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:2] -0.005876 0.000417 0.008206 0.006237 0.01514 ...
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:2] 0.00844 0.04382 0.0203 0.0348 0.02553 ...
Error in res2[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
Execution halted
```

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: Ohh, okay, you applied `eigen` on a `list`.  It should be `lapply(res2, function(x) eigen(x)$vectors[,1:2])` or so

Comment: I think it is because of the NA elements, `lapply(res2, function(x) eigen(replace(x, is.na(x), 0))$vectors[,1:2])` I don't whether it makes sense to replace NA with 0.  but this works without any error.  You may have to read that part about eigen.

Comment: In that case, it is better to post the question in crossvalidated i.e. (http://stats.stackexchange.com/) instead of stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the complete functional code is the following based in akrun's initial answer, his comment and some iterations

```
# http://stackoverflow.com/q/40429343/54964
set.seed(24)
A=541650
m1 <- matrix(1:A, ncol=4, nrow=A)

a=360; b=1505; c=4;
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/40430229/54964
m2 <- array(`length<-`(m1, a*b*c), dim = c(a,b,c))

res <- lapply(seq(dim(m2)[3]), function(i) cor(m2[,,i]))

res2 <- lapply(res, function(x) eigen(replace(x, is.na(x), 0))$vectors[,1:2])

str(res2)

e1 <- res[1]
e2 <- res[2]

str(e1)

str(e2)
```

Output

```
List of 4
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:2] -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 ...
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:2] -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 ...
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:2] -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 ...
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:2] -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 -0.0258 ...
List of 1
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:1505] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
List of 1
 $ : num [1:1505, 1:1505] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```